# Difference between maximum value in density plot from np.argmax() and figure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a large code that generates some `z` data from a pre-defined `x,y` grid.

After generating the `z` data (the file with some `z` data already generated is available [here](http://pastebin.com/nXba6MVv)) I interpolate it on a finer grid (using [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline)). Finally I obtain the maximum `z_max` value in this finer grid.

The issue is that the `y_max` coordinate value I get using `np.unravel_index()` and `np.argmax()`, is differerent from the value I see in the final image.

Using the MWE below, I get the `x_max, y_max` coordinates for the `z_max` value as:

```
40.5778894472 192.462311558
```

The `x_max` value seems to be correct judging by the figure seen below. But the `y_max` coordinate of the `z_max` value enclosed by the curves in the figure, is clearly not `~192.5`. It's closer to `210`.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Output image**

[image]

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.interpolate


def get_z_data(x, y):
    # Instead of generating the data, read them from a file that contains
    # the z data already generated. This is much faster and simpler.
    # Values passed are thus just for showing how the MWE works, and are
    # not actually  used.
    z = []
    with open('data.dat') as f:
        for l in f:
            z.append(float(l))

    return np.asarray(z)


# These values are used to generate the z data.
N = 25  # Grid size: N x N
x, y = np.linspace(20., 65., N), np.linspace(100., 300., N)
# Generate z data.
z = get_z_data(x, y)

# Define interpolating function.
z = z.reshape(N, N)
rbs = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z)

# Define a finer grid to interpolate on.
xi, yi = np.linspace(20., 65., 200), np.linspace(100., 300., 200)
# Get values on grid.
zi = rbs(xi, yi)

# x_max, y_max, z_max values.
max_idx = np.unravel_index(zi.argmax(), zi.shape)
print xi[max_idx[0]], yi[max_idx[1]], zi.max()

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(np.rot90(zi), vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[xi.min(), xi.max(), yi.min(), yi.max()],
           cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdBu_r'))
plt.contour(xi, yi, np.rot90(zi), 200, colors='k', linewidths=0.2)
ax.set_aspect(aspect='auto')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('out_fig.png', dpi=150)
```

Comment: Looks like your Y axis is just inverted. Problem is probably in your manual rotation and origin / axe range definition in imshow...

Comment: That could be @JulienBernu. I've been trying several different rotations and `origin` positions but so far I couldn't get it right. If you figure out which values I should use, please post it as an answer.

Comment: What is wrong with using the default display? (origin at top left corner, first index (xi) axis is down and second index (yi) is right) Do you absolutely _need_ to have your origin at the bottom left and xi as X and yi as Y?

Comment: Yes I do, but your comment made me find the answer. I need to change `plt.imshow` to  `origin='upper'` , and use `plt.contour(np.rot90(zi), 200, colors='k', linewidths=0.2, origin='upper', extent=[xi.min(), xi.max(), yi.min(), yi.max()])`. This produces the correct plot. If you'd like, you can generate an answer using this info and I'll mark it as accepted. It was your cmmt that made me realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since it's clearer than writing a long comment.

The issues were:

1. `origin` needs to be `upper` in `plt.imshow`.
2. The same `origin` and `extent` need to be added to `plt.contour`
3. The `xi, yi` values need to be removed from `plt.contour` since, as explained in [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contour): "This keyword [origin] is not active if X and Y are specified in the call to contour."

Those two lines code should thus look like:

```
plt.imshow(np.rot90(zi), vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max(), origin='upper', extent=[xi.min(), xi.max(), yi.min(), yi.max()], cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdBu_r'))
plt.contour(np.rot90(zi), 200, colors='k', linewidths=0.2, origin='upper', extent=[xi.min(), xi.max(), yi.min(), yi.max()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
plt.imshow(zi.transpose(), origin = 'bottom')
```

Comment: Simply using this line results in a badly distorted image.

Comment: Yes you still need to apply your `extent=...` and other formating, I was just answering the rotation problem...